Proof this is the only polynomial that satisfies equation

This is question B-2 from the 1985 Putnam competition. It is relatively straight forward, and with a bit of calculation we can see that the polynomial sequence $$f_{n}(x)=x(x+n)^{n-1}$$ works and we can prove by induction that this satisfies the sequence relation and initial conditions. My question is, how can I prove this is the only polynomial given $n$ and $x$ that satisfy the relations?

Induction again. At the start, $f_0$ is given, and the differential equation that is satisfied by $f_1$, together with $f_1(0)=0$, both determine $f_1$. (Integration is well defined up to a constant, the constant is determined by the value in $0$.) At the next step, same argument, from $f_1$ we obtain a unique $f_2$...

You can use the Picard-Lindelof Theorem to tell you that this is the only polynomial solution. This theorem tells you that in a neighborhood of $0$ there is a unique solution to the initial value problem
$$y'=(n+1)f_n(x+1),\ \ \ y(0)=0.$$
On its face this look like a local result, but in your case it is actually good enough to get a global result. To see this assume that $p(x)$ was some other polynomial solution, then on a neighborhood of $0$, $p(x)$ would agree with the polynomial you have found. However, if two polynomials agree on an interval then they are equal everywhere.
